# Setting the main view controller and displaying particular text and images in IOS Dev

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, pageviews

I am currently at a standstill with the app which i am trying to make.

I created a Page View Controller which can scroll across and show four different images and labels from an array all in one view controller. This is the code implementation:

```
_pageTitles = @[@"One", @"Two", @"Three", @"Four"];
_pageImages = @[@"1.png", @"2.png", @"3.png",@"4.png"];

// Create page view controller
self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

PageContentViewController *startingViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
NSArray *viewControllers = @[startingViewController];
[self.pageViewController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

// Change the size of page view controller
self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 30);

[self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
[self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
    return nil;
}

index--;
return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

 - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

if (index == NSNotFound) {
    return nil;
}

index++;
if (index == [self.pageTitles count]) {
    return nil;
}
return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
if (([self.pageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageTitles count])) {
    return nil;
}

// Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
pageContentViewController.imageFile = self.pageImages[index];
pageContentViewController.titleText = self.pageTitles[index];
pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;

return pageContentViewController;


}

- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:   (UIPageViewController*)pageViewController
 {
   return [self.pageTitles count];
}

 - (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
 {
  return 0;
 }
```

I would like to have only three pages show up everytime the app starts instead of all four pages without having to completely delete it from the array, but heres the catch. I would like to set a condition where it displays the middle page first and only the page before AND after the select page show up, with the final page being hidden.

e.g.

if page 3 is selected, pages 2,3, 4 can be seen within the page view
if page 2 is selected, pages 1,2,3 can be seen within the page view.

I have tried putting this into a simple term to understand but I simply cannot understand how I do this. I have spent all day trying to figure this out and I've had no luck!

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to create a class variable that is something like `currentlySelectedPageNumber` and then base all of your pageViewController delegation off of that value.  If the current selected is 2 then you don't need to change anything except for not allowing index to be greater than 2 (view number 3).  If currently selected is 3 then you just have to make your delegate functions return number 2 as 1, number 3 as 2, and number 4 as 3.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    NSInteger difference = index - currentlySelectedPageNumber;
    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound) && difference < 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

 - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((PageContentViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    NSInteger difference = index - currentlySelectedPageNumber;
    if (index == NSNotFound || difference > 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageTitles count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    //For this one you need to modify index based on your currently selected value
    index = currentlySelectedPageNumber - 1 + index;
    if (([self.pageTitles count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageTitles count]) || index < 0) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
    pageContentViewController.imageFile = self.pageImages[index];
    pageContentViewController.titleText = self.pageTitles[index];
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;

    return pageContentViewController;


}
```